# Регулярные выражения. Запретить пробел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Есть регулярное выражение:

```
if(!preg_match('#^([A-zА-я \-]*)$#ui', $_POST['name']))
```

мне нужно чтоб оно разрешало русские и английские буквы, и запрещало пробел

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: '[A-zА-я]' , так писать не корректно, в кодировке между большими и малыми буквами, в общем случае, есть и некоторые другие символы, например, "Z, [, ], ^, _, `, a" . Дабы не было недоразумений я бы рекомендовал [A-Za-z], данная конструкция означает все коды символов, начиная с [A] до [Z]. Т.к. буквы в кодировках идут подряд - это можно делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Регулярное выражения соответствующее строке состоящей из символов русского и английского языков выглядит так:

```
/^[a-zа-яё]+$/iu
```